# Static Analyzer Leak Warnings for CFBridgingRetain

Tags: objective-c, ios6, core-foundation

Can someone tell me why this is leaking? I am using CFRelease(), which I thought releases CFURLRef soundFileURLRef

**Call to function 'CFBridgingRetain' returns a Core Foundation object with a +1 retain count

Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1**

```
  -(void) playGuitarNote:(NSString *)noteVal {

    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundId);
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle,CFBridgingRetain(noteVal), CFSTR("aiff"), NULL);
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundId);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundId);
    CFRelease(soundFileURLRef);
    noteVal = nil;

}
```

Comment: It's not the `CFURLRef` that the analyzer is warning you about, it's the object you called `CFBridgingRetain()` with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `CFBridgingRetain()` there.  You should just use a `__bridge` cast:

```
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle,(__bridge CFStringRef)noteVal, CFSTR("aiff"), NULL);
```

You are not changing the ownership of `noteVal`, you're just passing it and telling the compiler to treat it as a different (but compatible) type.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `CFBridingRelease()`  to decrease the retain count.
So store a pointer to the object returned by `CFBridgingRetain()` and release it when you no longer need it.

See the [Documentation on Foundation Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFBridgingRetain)

Alternatively you could use a bridge cast instead of calling `CFBridgingRetain()`